# Best Way to Pull in Live Data From 'Root' Database On Demand

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Let me start by apologizing as I'm afraid this might be more of a "discussion" than an "answerable" question...but I'm running out of options.

I work for the Research Dept. for my city's public schools and am in charge of a reporting web site.  We use a third-party vendor (Infinite Campus/IC) solution to track information on our students -- attendance, behavior, grades, etc. The IC database sits in a cloud and they replicate the data to a local database controlled by our IT Dept.

I have created a series of SSIS packages that pull in data each night from our local database, so the reporting data is through the prior school day.  This has worked well, but recently users have requested that some of the data be viewed in real-time.  My database sits on a different server than the local IC database.

My first solution was to create a linked server from my server to the local IC server, and this was slow but worked.  Unfortunately, this put a strain on the local IC database, my IT Dept. freaked out and told me I could no longer do that.

My next & current solution was to create an SSIS package that would be called by a stored procedure.  The SSIS package would query the local IC database and bring in the needed data to my database.  This has been working well and is actually much quicker than using the linked server.  It takes about 30 seconds to pull in the data, process it and spit it out on the screen as opposed to the 2-3 minutes the linked server took.  It's been in place for about a month or so.

Yesterday, this live report turned into a parking lot -- the report says "loading" and just sits like that for hours.  It eventually will bring back the data.  I discovered the department head that I created this report for sent out an e-mail to all schools (approximately 160) encouraging them to check out the report.  As far as I can tell, about 90 people tried to run the report at the same time, and I guess this is what caused the traffic jam.

So my question is...is there a better way to pull in this data from the local IC database?  I'm kind of limited with what I can do, because I'm not in our IT Dept.  I think if I presented a solution to them, they may work with me, but it would have to be minimal impact on their end.  I'm good with SQL queries but I'm far from a db admin so I don't really know what options are available to me.

**UPDATE**
I talked to my IT Dept about doing transactional replication on the handful of tables that I needed, and as suspected it was quickly shot down.  What I decided to do was set up an SSIS package that is called via Job Scheduler and runs every 5 minutes.  The package only takes about 25-30 seconds to execute.  On the report, I've put a big "Last Updated 3/29/2018 5:50 PM" at the top of the report along with a message explaining the report gets updated every 5 minutes.  So far this morning, the report is running fantastically and the users I've checked in with seem to be satisfied.  I still wish my IT team was more open to replicating, but I guess that is a worry for another day.

Thanks to everybody who offered solutions and ideas!!

Comment: Have you looked at transactional replication? But I am afraid you may be correct. This is not a question with an "answer" which is considered off topic for SO. It is so broad and vague.

Comment: What is your reporting tool as well? It sounds like you're saying you can connect to the external data engine, so I'm *guessing* that you can query it, just not do much else? Is the external data engine also running SQL Server/Azure?

Comment: My reporting tool is asp.net as the framework, but trying to use as much HTML5/bootstrap as possible.  I use Web Services to connect to my database and pull back the data, and then format it inside of the website.

Comment: Sean -- I've thought a lot about transactional replication, the company I used to work for used it and it was fantastic.  I've brought up this subject here and IT kind of bristles at it.  But there's been a lot of turnover lately so I think I may try talking to them about it again and see if there's been a change of heart.

Comment: What's the requirement around real-time?  Meaning how stale can the data be - 15min, 30min, an hour?  If it is less, can you just write the queries direct to the IC database?  Also, what version of SQL are you using and how long does it take to refresh your local database?  Are you using an incremental loading process?

Comment: The IC front-end allows for a lot of errors in data entry.  It's controlled by a vendor and they say technically it's not errors and want to charge a hefty amount to make any changes. The solution was I would write a report that would show people data entry errors, they would go and correct them in IC and then come back and rerun my report to make sure the errors have been resolved.  People demand instant gratification that their errors are fixed, so they want the results as soon as they've made the edits.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2016, and my overnight process takes about an hour to refresh my database. I have approximately 15 SSIS jobs that load the various tables I need, they just grab all the data for the current school year and refresh my tables with the modifications.

Answer (score 0):

One option which I've done in the past is an "ETL on the Fly" method.
You set up an SSIS package as a dataflow but it writes to a DataReader Destination. This then becomes the source for your SSRS Report. In effect this means that when the SSRS report is run - it automatically runs the SSIS package and fetches the data - it can pass parameters into the SSIS report as well.
There's a bit of extra config involved but this is straightforward.

This article goes through it - 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1997/enable-ssis-as-data-source-type-on-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: Thanks, let me look into this and see if it could work. Up to this point my website is built on asp.net but using HTML5/bootstrap throughout.  I use Web Services to connect to my database. I'm very familiar with SSRS reporting but have been trying to not use it on my site -- trying to stay as "vendor free" as possible.  But as I mentioned, I may not have a choice at this point...